# Android build system command mm fails with this error "The import org.mockito cannot be resolved"

Tags: mockito

I am using **Android** build system command mm to create an **apk** file for unit testing. I use `mockito` in the test classes and therefore I imported it in my code:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

mm terminates with this error:

> ERROR: : The import org.mockito cannot be
>   resolved ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Could anyone know what has caused this issue and how it can be solved?

Comment: Is it Java? If so, you need to have Mockto's JAR somewhere on your build path.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Comment: It is java. The mockito's jar is declared in the gradle file. I have already looked at the pages you mentioned. The point is that I am not using Android Studio for running tests. I used mm command to make only the test apk. Tests that don't need mocking are created and run perfectly using mm. but when mock is involved, it can not import the mockito class. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that does not let gradle be involved. Any feedback on this?